# How does one pass a json file or object in a POST request using Python module 'requests'

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, typeerror

I am using a site's REST API's and have been primarily using Python's 'requests' module to GET json responses. The goal of the GET requests are to ultimately pull a user's form response which ends up being a complex json document. To deal with this:

```
user_form_submission = requests.get('https://www.url/doc.json',
        auth = (api_key, secret),
        params = params)

python_obj = json.loads(user_form_submission.text)
trimmed_dict = python_obj['key'][0]['keys']
```

For context, this is what trimmed_dict would look like formatted as .json:

```
{
    "Date": { "value": "2020-04-26", "type": "date" },
    "Location": {
      "value": "Test ",
      "type": "text",
      "geostamp": "lat=34.00000, long=-77.00000, alt=17.986118, hAccuracy=65.000000, vAccuracy=10.000000, timestamp=2020-04-26T23:39:56Z"
    },
    "form": {
      "value": [
        {
          "form_Details": {
            "value": [
              {
                "code": {
                  "value": "0000000000",
                  "type": "barcode"
                },
                "Name": { "value": "bob", "type": "text" }
              }
            ],
            "type": "group"
          },
          "Subtotal": { "value": "4", "type": "decimal" },
          "form_detail2": {
            "value": [
              {
                "name": {
                  "value": "billy",
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "code": {
                  "value": "00101001",
                  "type": "barcode"
                },
                "Classification": {
                  "value": "person",
                  "type": "select1"
                },
                "Start_Time": { "value": "19:43:00", "type": "time" },
                "time": { "value": "4", "type": "decimal" }
                }
            ],
      "type": "subform"}
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

Now I have a portion of the json that contains both the useful and useless. From this point, can I pass this obj in a POST? I've tried every way that I can think of approaching it, and have been shut down.

Understanding how I want to go about this, this is how I thought it would go:

```
json_post = requests.post(' https://url/api/doc.json', 
        auth = (api_key, secret), 
        json = {
            "form_id" : 'https://url.form.com/formid',
            'payload':{
                 json.dumps(trimmed_dict)
             }})
```

But, when I do this, I get the following error --

```
    TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable
```

How can I push this dict through this POST? If there's a more effective way of going about it, I am very open to suggestion.

Comment: did you try converting json data into python dict and use that dict value instead of json variable name?

Comment: Well that's what json.loads does, right? It takes a json doc and converts it into whatever the appropriate python objs are from the json structure. python_obj is type dict in my example. Are you asking if I tried to pass the entire python_obj before trimming it down? No, I haven't, I assume it will raise 'set cannot be json serializable' but I'll go ahead and test it for the heck of it.

Comment: ```
json_post = requests.post(' https://url/api/doc.json', 
        auth = (api_key, secret), 
        json = {
            "form_id" : 'https://url.form.com/formid',
            'payload':{
                 json.dumps(python_obj)
             }})
```
raised TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the curly braces around `json.dumps(trimmed_dict)`.  `json.dumps` turns your `trimmed_dict` into a string, which becomes a python `set` when surrounded with braces.

Additionally you could remove `json.dumps` and plug the `trimmed_dict` into the structure directly as the value associated with `payload`.

Comment: I'll be damned. I assumed since the content type of the post was json that the body would have to be formatted as such before the request. But nope, so I tried exactly what you suggested and ' 'payload':trimmed_dict ' gave back a 201 server status, and ' 'payload': json.dumps(trimmed_dict) ' 400 me. The post crashes the app that it goes too, but it's a step in the right direction. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra {} from the payload. payload itself is a key and `json.dumps(trimmed_dict)` as a value is enough

```
json_post = requests.post(' https://url/api/doc.json', 
        auth = (api_key, secret), 
        json = {
            "form_id" : 'https://url.form.com/formid',
            "payload": json.dumps(trimmed_dict)
             })
```

Comment: Tried this out and it's definitely the way I should have approached this, but the server is responding with a 400 towards it. When I just use the python obj without the json.dumps serializing it, server is sends a 201. Not entirely sure why yet, but thank you for the suggestion!